# How to set wallpaper without making a few black on screen

Tags: android

I`m developing a feature in my application that can change wallpaper automatically(like a microsoft launcher widget name wallpaper).

I use this code to change my wallpaper, it works, but when it changes my wallpaper my screen turns black firstly and shows new wallpaper later(turn black about 100ms)

I use a theme to show the wallpaper

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

I run it on pixel Android9.0

Another question is after I change my wallpaper frequently my screen will be black permanently, until I restart my phone(but I can get the new wallpaper by using `manager.getDrawable()`)

```
    ThreadPoolUtils.execute(()->{
        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Slog.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I am so surprised that microsoft launcher can change my wallpaper without turing my screen black.

Please help me, I really want to know how, it makes best experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(framelayout.getWidth(),
                        framelayout.getHeight()
                        , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                framelayout.draw(canvas);


                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set background successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: thx! I am trying to pass my rootlayout to my fragment.What`s the use of framelayout.draw(canvas);

Comment: What you want to set as wallpaper your rootlayout?? I am generating bitmap of Framelayout and set as wallpaper

Comment: sorry i am noob.....I thought i should pass my root layout and get it`s width and height as you do......

Comment: ya do that way.